# Есть ли возможность узнать индекс считываемоего из .txt символа?

Tags: java

Необходимо считывать из нескольких .txt файлов построчно символы и записывать в массив. Затем, после того, как первые строчки прочитаны во всех файлах и обработаны, такую же операцию провести со следующими строками. Так пока файлы не закончатся.

Есть ли возможность запоминать номер строчки в файле, на котором остановились, чтобы потом в нему просто вернуться?

ByfferedReader.readline() не подходит, так как файлов сразу несколько и их количество может изменяться.

Благодаря Vladimir разобралась. 
Нашла еще хороший материал, который наглядно пояснил и разжевал.

[Урок 4. RandomAccessFile и его возможности](https://devcolibri.com/%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA-4-randomaccessfile-%D0%B8-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8/)

Comment: и почему не подходит? Как по мне более чем подходит.

Comment: На каждый файл создаете свой `ByfferedReader` и читаете из него, когда надо. В конце делаете `close`. Если, конечно у вас не 100500 файлов. Или присмотритесь к `java.io.RandomAccessFile` - он умеет запоминать позицию в файле и смещаться к ней.

Comment: Спасибо, 2 вариант подошел.